# Regular expression search usage in Python 3.6

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6, and have several thousand text documents that I have scanned from PDF files into a python 3 dictionary as a string. Each document is a separate dictionary entry of a single string. I am trying to use a regular expression search to extract the name and address information from each page. I have identified that the last name is always preceded by “Room #______” and followed by “Last/“  I have tried to do this, but it doesn’t seem to work. I am not at all familiar with lookaround constructs. Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong? My final code will have several of these searches, this is only the first.

```
memberRecord = memberData[1]
memberRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (?<=Room #______)\w+(?=Last)
    $
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
mo = memberRegex.search(memberRecord)
```

Comment: You do not account for any whitespace or non-word chars in between `Room #____`, you word and `Last`. Try `Room #______(.*?)Last` and when a match is found, grab `mo.group(1)`.

Comment: Thanks you Wiktor. I was trying to make it too complicated apparently! This worked:  
    memberRegex = re.compile(r'(Room #______)(.*)(Last)')  
    mo = memberRegex.search(memrec)  
    print(mo.group(2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not account for any whitespace or non-word chars in between `Room #____`, you word and `Last`. The value you need can be accessed after a match is found via  `mo.group(1)`:

```
memberRegex = re.compile(r'Room #______(.*?)Last', re.DOTALL)
mo = memberRegex.search(memberRecord)
if mo:
    print(mo.group(1))
```

Note that `re.DOTALL` flag will allow `.` to match across lines and `*?` lazy quantifier will match as few any characters as possible, up to the *first* `Last`. If you need to get to the *last* occurrence of `Last`, replace `*?` with `*` (greedy quantifier version).